# How can I stop Ajax call triggering error function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is the jsp page I'm using.I wrote javascript inside jsp. I have done some validation on form and then ajax call is used. Please check whether I have done something wrong in jsp.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Register page</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Student registration form:</h3>

<form action="RegisterController" method="get" id="registerForm" name="stud"  >
<table>
 <tr>
 <td><label>Username:</label></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"></td><td><label id="nameId"></label></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><label>Email id:</label></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td><td><label id="emailId"></label></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><label>Contact No:</label></td>
 <td><input type="number" name="contact" id="contact"></td><td><label id="contactId"></label></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><label>Address:</label></td>
 <td><textarea name="address" rows="3" cols="20" id="address"></textarea></td><td><label id="addressId"></label></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>Select City:</td>
 <td>
 <input type="text" list="city" name="cities" id="cities">
 <datalist id="city">
  <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
  <option value="Pune">Pune</option>
  <option value="Nashik">Nashik</option>
  <option value="Solapur">Solapur</option>
 </datalist>
 </td><td>
 <label id="cityId"></label>
 </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>Gender:</td>
 <td><input id="r1" type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<input id="r2" type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</td><td><label id="genderId"></label></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><label>Courses:</label></td>
 <td>Java<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" name="course" value="java">Spark<input id="cb2" type="checkbox" name="course" value="spark">Hadoop<input id="cb3" type="checkbox" name="course" value="hadoop">PHP<input id="cb4" type="checkbox" name="course" value="php"></td><td><label id="courseId"></label></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>Select Time Preferable</td>
 <td>
 <select name="batches" id="batches">
  <option value="7 am to 8 am">7 am to 8 am</option>
  <option value="9 am to 10 am">9 am to 10 am</option>
  <option value="11 am to 12 pm">11 am to 12 pm</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Register" id="Register"><br><br>
</form>
<a href="index.jsp">Go to login page</a>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#registerForm').submit(function(es){
  es.preventDefault();
  
  var name=$('#uname').val();
  var email=$('#email').val();
  var contact=$('#contact').val();
  var address=$('#address').val();
  var city=$('#cities').val();
  var gender1=$('#r1').is(":checked");
  var gender2=$('#r2').is(":checked");
  var cbOne=$('#cb1').is(":checked");
  var cbTwo=$('#cb2').is(":checked");
  var cbThree=$('#cb3').is(":checked");
  var cbFour=$('#cb4').is(":checked");
  
  $('.error').remove();
  
  //validating fields of form
  if(name.length<=0){
   $('#nameId').after('<span class="error" style="color:red">Enter the Username</span>');
   
  }
  if(contact.length!=10){
   $('#contactId').after('<span class="error" style="color:red">Enter valid contact number</span>');
   
  }
  if(address.length<=0){
   $('#addressId').after('<span class="error" style="color:red">Enter the address</span>');
   
  }
  if(city.length<=0){
   $('#cityId').after('<span class="error" style="color:red">Enter the city</span>');
   
  }
  if(!(gender1||gender2)){
   $('#genderId').after('<span class="error" style="color:red">Select gender</span>');
   
  }
  if(!(cbOne||cbTwo||cbThree||cbFour)){
   $('#courseId').after('<span class="error" style="color:red">Select at least one course</span>')
   
  }
  if(email.length<=0){
   $('#emailId').after('<span class="error" style="color:red">Enter the email</span>');
   
  }
  else{
   //var regEx=/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
   //var regEx=/^\w+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
   var regEx=/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[com]{3}$/;
   var validEmail=regEx.test(email);
   if(!validEmail){
    $('#emailId').after('<span class="error" style="color:red">Enter valid email</span>');
    
   }
  }
  
  //data to be passed
  var form_data={
    
    username:$('#uname').val(),
    email:$('#email').val(),
    contact:$('#contact').val(),
    address:$('#address').val(),
    city:$('#cities').val(),
    
    batch:$('#batches').val()
    
    
  };
  
  //ajax call goes here
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: './RegisterController',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(){
   
       console.log("Sucess: ");
    
    },
    error : function(message) {

     alert("error: "+message);
    
   }
  });
  
  
 });
} );
</script>
</html>
```

I'm creating a registration form and want to transfer data of form using ajax call.I wrote the javascript for it. But Ajax call is triggering error function. I'm not getting what is wrong in the code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#registerForm').submit(function(es){
  es.preventDefault();

        var form_data={
                        username:$('#uname').val(),
   email:$('#email').val(),
   contact:$('#contact').val(),
   address:$('#address').val(),
   city:$('#cities').val(),
   batch:$('#batches').val()
                      };

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'RegisterController',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(){
       console.log("Sucess: ");
    
    },
    error : function(message) {

     alert("error: "+message);
    
   }
  });
  
  
 });
} );
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats the error in console

Comment: There is no error in console.

Comment: check on network tab whether all the data are passing in header

Comment: No, data is not passing. It is not forwarding to controller. Staying on same jsp.

Comment: post ur HTML code too, you may have given return false on form submit

Comment: Put a debug point at RegisterController Method and check passed data is like formdata:{form_data} or not?

Comment: Can you please do this: `success: function(res){ console.log("Sucess: " + res); }` and tell us the result?

Answer (score 0):

The url you are providing is it correct.It seems you are writing the controller name not path which is directing to the method of that particular controller

Comment: Url is not problem it is giving same output with full path '/test/controller/RegisterController' and with 'RegisterController' also. I tried both.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put response inside success function to check if you got response from your Url?

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'RegisterController',
      data: form_data,
      success: function(response){
         console.log("Sucess:" + response );

      },
```

Comment: Yes , I tried also that, still it triggers error function.